# PHP doesn't read folder size when directory contains accented characters

Tags: php, character, size, diacritics

I'm on Ubuntu and I have some directories that contain special characters, like 'š', 'č', 'ü' and the like.

I'm using the following code:

```
$path = "/var/www/html/folder/$var1";
$io = popen ( '/usr/bin/du -sk ' . escapeshellarg($path), 'r' );
$size = fgets ( $io );
```

I use `escapeshellarg($path)` because some of my directories contain spaces, and this solution works fine, and when displaying $path on my website, it is displayed correctly. However, $size doesn't return anything for directories with special characters.

What can I do to make it work?

Sample output:

```
echo 'Directory: ' . $path . ' => Size: ' . $size . '<br>';


Directory: /var/www/html/folder/y/x => Size: 3464
Directory: /var/www/html/folder/ü/x => Size: 
Directory: /var/www/html/folder/š/x => Size:
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a command line call with `shell_exec()` to get the size?  I know on windows you can use something like this `$filename= iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $filename)` for the filename not sure about Linux

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I've just started with php and this is the first time I'm attempting anything like this. I haven't tried anything else. Adding iconv doesn't solve the problem for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: `du -sk ` and `du -sch` both output the same data, the only difference being one outputs kilobytes, the other one megabytes. I still can't get the size of directories with accented characters.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem lies in the $path variable not being read correctly and not elsewhere. To clarify, I did try -sch, and the problem remained.

Comment: Actually, you should output the results of `escapeshellarg($path)` and not just `$path`.   escapeshellarg may remove some of those chars as part of it's cleaning process.  What your really interested in is the output of that and not the input.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Great thank you, this was the mistake! `escapeshellarg($path)`removes the special characters. The problem I'm left with now, is again how to deal with spaces in directory names.

Comment: See this link, http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php#99213 which is what gave me the idea.  `When escapeshellarg() was stripping my non-ASCII characters from a UTF-8 string, adding the following fixed the problem:setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");`  Not sure it will work but, worth a shot right...

Comment: The solution worked like a charm, thank you @ArtisticPhoenix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discovered in the comments, You can do this:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

I got the inspiration for this from a comment on the PHP document page for `escapeshellarg`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php#99213

> When escapeshellarg() was stripping my non-ASCII characters from a UTF-8 string, adding the following fixed the problem: `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");`

I noticed in your debugging output you were simply echoing `$path` when what we really want to see is the results of `escapeshellarg` which is what gets passed to the command line, not it's input.  After checking that the problem became more clear.

Also when I tested this in a sandbox it appeard to not remove those so I wasn't sure it would work.  But I know when viewing things on the web a lot depends on the server settings, content types etc.  In both cases there is no way for me to really know, because I don't know how either server (yours or the sandbox) is setup.

So i figured it was worth mentioning.

Sandbox code:

```
 echo escapeshellarg("fooščü");
```

Output

```
'fooščü' //looks like it didnt remove them
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c801603c9f7e56a5979623f217c2c93bcbd95b2)

I reposed the comment, above, for posterity.

Personally I never ran into this issue, so I am glad we were able to work it out.

Cheers!